# Can the deleted question about custom bootable appliance be undeleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, undelete-request

Is there any way to appeal a deleted question?  I spent a few minutes coming up with a constructive answer for a very badly worded question, and the whole lot just vanished a minute or so after I posted, no votes or anything.  It's a bit annoying, since it was a genuinely interesting programming question (basically about building a custom Linux distro/appliance to run an app inside, it used to live [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555515)).  It was clearly an English-not-first-language user, and I really think if they had been given a chance to reword their question it would have been worth keeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user who posted the question deleted it. So I don't think the problem was that they didn't get a chance.

You can post the question yourself if you think it's interesting.

Comment: OK, that explains it then!  Thanks.  I assumed an enthusastic moderater had smacked it :)  I might recreate the question at some point, but it's caused me to get distracted and start playing with suse studio :)

Comment: Nah, we'd never do that. ahem.

Answer (score 2):

It was deleted by the author (thanks for posting the link; it would have been hard to track without it); the system prevents against author-based deletions when a few answers are "in" and it is upvoted. You could always ask the question yourself, with your suitable wording? History suggests it may be an idea to leave it a little while before answering yourself, though. But answering your own question is fine.